# Keyword not supported in Connection String: 'database'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio, connection

Very new to C# and VS2012.

I'm trying to connect to a local database connection.

Here is the code

```
        string selectSql = "select * from Tasks";
        string connectionString = "Data Source=adamssqlserver;database=master;Integrated Security=true;";

        using (var cn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCeCommand(selectSql, cn))
        {
            cn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {

                //do something

            }
        }
```

Here is the error

> Keyword not supported: 'database'.

If I put in Initial Catalog first

> "Data Source=adamssqlserver;Initial Catalog=etc;"

Then the error gives the same message but for "Initial Catalog".

Here is my data connection

[image]

Comment: Does a "CE" connection only support one database/source or something else wonky? In a *normal* SQL Server connection (`SqlConnection`), both syntaxes posted would have worked fine.

Comment: What edition of SQL Server are you using?  You're using the CE objects, but your connection string appears to be for a full SQL server.

Comment: I've got SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2012 installed on my box.  But I believe it is using SQL Server 2012, given that the title I gave it was adamssqlserver.  Is CE not for full SQL Server connections?

Comment: @adam Never used CE (which stands for "Compact Edition" in Microsoft lingo), but switch it to `SqlConnection` and try again :D

Comment: That was it!  Now I get to cn.Open() and then it fails dramatically.  Guess I'll research and possibly open a new post, new issue.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `SqlCeConnection` not a `SqlConnection`

This class (SqlCeConnection) is for `Sql Compact Edition` where the syntax rules of the connection string are different. For example:

```
Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;
```

Instead your connection string is for a `Sql Server` or `Sql Server Express`.
So, if your target database is a SqlServer db as your tag indicates then you need to use

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(selectSql, cn))
{
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm now to the cn.Open(); line, which generates a dramatic error message ------------------------------- -------------------------- ---------------- "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Data Source, try Server, e.g:

```
string connectionString = "Server=adamssqlserver;Database=master";
```

Comment: This -->  connectionString = "Server=adamssqlserver;Database=master;Integrated Security=true;";    Gives the error messages --> Keyword not supported: 'server'.

Comment: Indeed, having just read the other comments posted on your question I see I missed you are using CE, in which case Data Source is the correct keyword, followed by "Initial Catalogue".

Answer (score 0):

This [website](http://www.connectionstrings.com/) contains good information for setting up connection string.  There are so many options I usually have to turn to a reference to get it set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reminder: when using MS Access databases, you need to use OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand, not SqlConnection and SqlCommand. 'Provider' in the connection string for SqlConnection is invalid AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the " from the connection string section.

Should be

```
<add name="StevenTestEntities" 
connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.TestModel.csdl|res://*/Model.TestModel.ssdl|res://*/Model.TestModel.msl;
provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=Data Source=D000097;
Initial Catalog=StevenTest;
Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&qout;"
providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Try that out.